# undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass in @cart.items.each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

These are my **pruduct.rb, cart.eb and item.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessible :category_id, :color, :description, :price, :size, :title, :product_type, :sub_category_id, :image_url

  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :sub_category
  has_many :items
end
```

**Cart.rb**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Item.rb**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base


attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id,:product

  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
end
```

The **ItemContoller**

```
class ItemController < ApplicationController

def create
    @cart=current_cart
    product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @item=@cart.items.build(product: product)
    redirect_to clothes_path
    flash.now[:success]="Product successfully added to Cart"
  end

end
```

Now in my **views** when I want to show the **cart contents** like

```
<%= @cart.items.each do |item| %>
```

The **current_cart** method

```
def current_cart
cart=Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    cart=Cart.create
    session[:cart_id]=cart.id
    cart
  end
```

it gives me this error

> undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass

What is wrong here?
I'm following the example **Agile web Developement with Rails** book.

Comment: the error indicates the @cart variable is nil. Show us your current_cart helper method

Comment: What does the index action in your ItemController look like?

Comment: I don't have any index action. Why do I need that?

Comment: @AlthafHamez added the current_cart method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you redirect to cloths_path from ItemController's create action @cart instance variable will not be available to cloth's controller index action. to need to reset it some how in index action

```
for eg: - 

you can pass cart id to it and find it in index cloth's action

redirect_to clothes_path, card_id: @cart.id

and in cloth's index action do 

@cart = Cart.find params[:cart_id]


create a mathod in application controller, and after u create a new cart, save its id in session, like

session[:cart] = @cart.id

def current_cart
  @cart = Cart.find session[:cart_id]
end

and in view use current_cart method instead of @cart
```

Comment: Actually I waant that @cart instance variable accross all controlles. so i made a new method in application_controller and added the last line of yours to it. But it's still not working.

Comment: That is only working for ClothController. i want to access the @cart variable in all the views of the application

Comment: @Mrudul_T read it carefully at the end, it says to create a method in application controller

Comment: @SachinSingh You know, you really could use capital letters, punctuation, full sentences, and proper formatting so we don't have to try to decipher your almost entirely unintelligible answers.

Comment: @coreyward sorry about that.

Comment: I got that right.One thing more I want is after **adding a product to cart** I want to redirect to the same page from where the user added it. I tried saving the url with **request.url** and **request.original_url** but that gives **the page isn't redirecting properly error**. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You're redirecting to `clothes_path` (`redirect_to clothes_path`) and it seems you have `ClothController`. This controller should contain `index` method to render index page. Assign `current_cart` to `@cart` there:

```
class ClothController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @cart = current_cart
  end

  ...

end
```

---

**UPDATE**

To make `@cart` available in all views of `Cloth` controller there is a method `before_filter` where you can set `@cart` variable. You can add this definitions in your required controllers. For more details - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

```
class ClothController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_current_cart

  def index
  end

  ...

  private

  def set_current_cart
    @cart = current_cart
  end

end
```

`current_cart` method should be implemented as helper to be available in all controllers. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

---

**UPDATE 2**

Implement a helper in `/app/helpers/cart_helper.rb`:

```
module CartHelper

  def current_cart
    # Your current cart method code
  end

end
```

And include it into required controllers. `current_cart` method will be available in all views of controllers which contain `CartHelper`.

```
class ClothController < ApplicationController
  include CartHelper

  ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah it's working for the clothes controller. But how to make that @cart instance variable to available for all controllers or all the views

Comment: by all views I mean all views of all the controllers. across all the application views