# Iterating over Instance variable printing unwanted things

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

My questions details are here

> [undefined method `items' for nil:NilClass in @cart.items.each](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17953016/1552570)

The extra things I added were a **cart** method in application controller and also made it **helper_method** to make it available in all views across the application

```
helper_method :cart

def cart
    @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  end
```

When in my view I iterate over the @cart variable like this

```
    <%= cart.items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.product.title%></td>
        <td><%= item.product.price%></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
```

It shows this

[image]

Why is printing that upper thing? I know that is the output of **item.product.title** and all such variables. How to remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is printing that upper thing?

Because you are telling it to. When you surround ruby code with `<%= %>` you are telling it to render the result of the enclosed code. Since you are putting it around the `each` block it is displaying the result of `each`, which is the collection it was called on.

To remove it, just use `<% %>` instead.

Comment: That was a terrible silly typo. Thanks for the quick answer.